# Which is more efficient for raspistill: `-vf -hf` or `-rot 180'? (Raspberry Pi Zero W)

Tags: camera, raspicam, image, power-management

According to [the official documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/camera/raspicam/raspistill.md),

> With the camera placed upside-down, the image must be rotated 180° to be displayed correctly. The way to correct for this is to apply both a vertical and a horizontal flip by passing in the -vf and -hf flags:
>
> `raspistill -vf -hf -o cam2.jpg`

An astute reader will also notice that `-rot 180` yields the same result.

So in the use case of a raspberry pi zero w with official camera (noir or daylight), which is more efficient?

*Note:* Using `power-management` tag because I'm wondering if this could impact lower-power usage deployments.